# Capture time of ng-click event AngularJS - is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm wondering is there a way to capture the time of event in AngularJS?

For example:

I have three buttons `(button A, button B, button C)` with `ng-click` directive. I'm clicking the `button A` and `some magic` tells me the time of clicked this button. Next, I'm clicking the `button B` and the same `magic` tells me the time of this event.

Is it possible to achieve it in `AngularJS`? Or maybe - does `HTML` provide something like this?

edit: Maybe not only the ng-click event.

Comment: Do you need to register the time with your event is consuming? You could register the time millis before and after your event: var time = new Date().getTime(); yourEvent(); time = new Date().getTime() - time;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Date() function inside your click function like :

Html :

```
<button ng-click="A()">click me</button>
```

inside controller :

```
$scope.A = function(){
              console.log('you click A on ', Date());
           }
```

you get current DateTime.

you can pass this in any variable and bind with your html code like

```
$scope.A = function(){
              console.log('you click A on ', Date());
              $scope.button_A = Date();
           }
```

and in html `{{button_A}}`

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just use javascripts date object in the function that is called

```
var currentTime = new Date()
var hours = currentTime.getHours()
var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()
if (minutes < 10){
    minutes = "0" + minutes
}
document.write(hours + ":" + minutes  + " ")
if(hours > 11){
   document.write("PM")
} else {
 document.write("AM")
}
```

Will print the current time, maybe you want to save it in a variable instead

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you call a `function` with the `ng-click directive` that will store the actual time in a `variable` of your `scope` ? You could use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to manipulate `time`.

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.timeA;

    $scope.storeTime = function() {
        $scope.timeA = moment().format();
    };
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <button ng-click="storeTime()">Button A</button>
    Time A: {{timeA}}
</div>
```

See [working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/16136/)

Comment: Thanks for help also!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

function MainCtrl(){
var vm = this;
vm.setTime = setTime;
vm.test = 'time';

function setTime(){
   vm.test = new Date();
 }
}
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl as mainCtrl">
   {{mainCtrl.test}}
   <button ng-click="mainCtrl.setTime();">Button</button>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVqBYg

Regards!